# Why doesn't shapeless.Nat have a method to access its value at runtime?

Tags: scala, shapeless

Here is an example program that requires `shapeless.Nat` to be able to produce its value at runtime even though its value is not known at comile time:

```
case class Command[N <: Nat](name: String, args: Sized[List[String], N])
case class InvokeCommand[N <: Nat, A](ref: Command[N], args: Sized[List[A], N])

object Program {

  val commands: List[Command[Nat]] = List(
    Command("foo", Sized("t", "r", "f")),
    Command("bar", Sized("h", "i")))

  def callCommand[A](name: String, args: List[A]): Option[InvokeCommand] = {
    val command = commands.find(_.name ≟ name)
    args.sized(command.args.size).map(InvokeCommand(command, _))
  }
}
```

This still yields a program that has far more static type guarantees than if it were not using `shapeless.Nat` at all. This program assumes that `Sized` has a `size` method which returns a `shapeless.Nat` which is not the case but would be fairly straightforward to implement.

So my question is why is it that `shapeless.Nat` does not have a `toInt` method (also straightforward to implement) that would allow a new version of the `sized` method to compile and work in this scenario where the runtime value of `N` is not known at compile time?

What am I missing or should I open a PR for Shapeless?

Comment: With the right import (`import shapeless.syntax.nat`) `Nat` has a `toInt` method. See https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/ab081796c183530efdd8b29dab8fee1fee7c61f9/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/syntax/nat.scala#L46

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Yes, but that `toInt` method requires the actual "value" of the `Nat` to be known at compile time. That's because it needs an instance of the `ToInt` typeclass and shapeless only provides instances for `Succ` and `_0`. Presumably Shapeless does it this way specifically to avoid being able to call `toInt` on a value of type `Nat` that does not have a more specific type (meaning its value is unknown at compile time) and I guess the reason for that is the crux of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intention is that uses of the `Nat` type be mainly phantom and affect type checking and computation via type inference and implicit resolution. Where this is the case there's no need for any runtime represention, and the additional storage that would be required would be wasted. Where there is a need for a runtime representation the the `ToInt` type class can provide it, though clearly with more ceremony than an intrinsic `toInt` method.

In summary, this is "by design": things could have been done differently, but they are as intended.